# Breaking $100 banknotes into smaller denominations while in the US

Tags: usa, money

I will be travelling to the US and have some (clarification: 7 or 8) 100 USD banknotes. When I arrive there, I would like to change them into 5/10/20 USD banknotes, to use when credit cards are impractical (probably mostly tips or small purchases).

Is it acceptable / customary / expected / normal to walk into a random bank office and ask for such change? Is there a fee for the change?

Any other options?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89087/discussion-on-question-by-woj-changing-usd-banknotes-into-smaller-pieces-while-i).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> Is it acceptable / customary / expected / normal to walk into a random bank office and ask for such change? Is there a fee for the change?

It is acceptable.  Some banks may be more accommodating than others.  I would expect smaller banks and those that emphasize customer service to be among the former.  Larger commercial banks are more likely to be among the latter.  There should be no fee.

> Any other options?

Make small purchases, one for each $100 note.  To be courteous, tell the cashier that you have no smaller banknotes before you present the merchandise, to give an opportunity to decline the transaction if the store lacks sufficient small change.  Many stores refuse to accept $100 bills altogether, so you may have to try a few places before you'll find one that will accommodate you.

In practice, people commonly pay with $20 notes, so most stores will have a large number of these on hand.  Making a $5 purchase with a $100 note isn't likely to cause more inconvenience than making the same purchase with a $20 note.

Comment: You can also try find a store with an automated checkout machine that is set up to handle cash and $100 bills, if you don't like the idea of the needing to talk to a cashier. I know my local grocery stores don't have a problem with it. Also, casinos (if there happens to be one nearby) are of course used to dealing with large bills (cashiers or change machines).

Comment: @pboss3010 do the automated checkouts take $100 bills? In UK the max that most will accept is £20 (ie they refuse the £50).

Comment: Making a small purchase at the airport when you arrive would be a great way of doing this. Of course, you'll pay a lot for that bottle of water or pack of gum, but they will be used to international travelers coming to town and not having small bills in hand.

Comment: I was thinking about that as well @WeatherVane. There are quite a number of smaller stores in the US that won't accept $100s because they're too often counterfeited and they don't want to deal with the risk. Many of the "big box" stores will take them because they have a machine at each register to check bills (I've seen some places scan $20s) to ensure they're legit, but smaller corner market places usually won't.

Comment: @WeatherVane It'll depend on the store, of course, but the local major grocery chains and the big box retailers' automated checkouts don't seem to have an issue. The machines had a little "accepts $1 ... $100" sign on it, I tried it and got back the right change.

Comment: Lots of servers or other people who make money in cash tips are generally also happy to change for you since they have more small bills than they could want.

Comment: @FreeMan they may be used to it.  In my experience with international airports in the US, it can really go either way.  Some people are surprisingly unaware of the needs of arriving international travelers, which paradoxically makes those who are aware also come as a surprise.

Comment: I don't imagine $800 in hundreds would be a big deal, but don't banks start to have restrictions on what they can do with quantities of cash larger than a certain amount, due to money laundering laws? For large enough amounts, I believe they will start demanding to know things like the source of the money.

Comment: @BenCrowell the threshold is $10,000, so this question doesn't come anywhere close to having to worry about that.  There's no restriction on what you can do with cash in amounts that large or larger, but there is a requirement for the bank to report such transactions. Anyone entering (or leaving) the US with cash and cash equivalents worth $10,000 or more, counting things denominated in foreign currency by converting the value to US dollars, must also report this to customs.

Comment: Walk into any bank, +1.  If your bank doesn't do this, and *for free* nonetheless, please list them below in bold capital letters.

Comment: Agreed with @FreeMan regarding $100 bills at shops. Many will refuse $100 bills and some will refuse $50, due to counterfeiting concerns. It's not about not having enough change, it's about not wanting to give out $90+ in change and get stuck with a fake $100 note. A bank is a better bet for breaking $100 notes.

Comment: @reirab While the US is very card-friendly, and cards are accepted almost everywhere, it's still a good idea for a visitor to carry some cash, as there are a few and far between random places where a foreign issued card Just Doesn't Work At All for no obvious reason. And of course they usually don't work at gas station pumps for the obvious reason (but can be used inside the store). But $800 is probably way overdoing it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Regarding gas stations, the pumps don't take cash either, so, if you're going to go inside anyway, you may as well use your card. :) But, yeah, I agree that it's a good idea to carry some cash when traveling (not just in the U.S., but pretty much anywhere.) That said, living in the U.S., my usage of cash within the U.S. is probably something like $200-300 _per year_.

Comment: And oh, make those purchases in the middle of the business day, as early in the day stores won't yet have had enough cash transactions to build up enough change to break large notes.

Comment: @MichaelHampton As a US citizen, I'm not sure how well things work here with foreign cards, but we had credit card issues on 4 different trips to Europe. Cards were suspended for potential fraud due to international use, _despite_ us telling the card issuers _ahead of time_ that we would be traveling. Having cash on had was _vital_ to eating. Depending on how many people the OP is feeding, $800 could go pretty quickly...

Comment: There is definitely a distrust of $100 bills. Couple that with "foreigner" and you will probably have trouble changing them.

Answer (score 35):

If you're staying at a hotel, you could ask at the front desk.  Cash is still common enough in the USA that I would expect that most hotels would have enough cash on hand to accommodate you.

While I would be surprised if a "nice" hotel were unable to do this, I should say that I have never actually tried it myself.

Comment: N+1, because in my experience I use this at hotels in America allll the time.  If they don't, I'd be surprised; but any normal bank nearby would be able to break the 100 for you, and almost any petrol station as well.

Comment: @Mikey A lot of US gas stations ("petrol" stations to you Brits ;) won't accept any bill larger than a $20 (and have numerous signs saying so) because of the risk of taking in counterfeits. If they accept a counterfeit $20, they're out less cash. Also, small purchases with big bills are a popular way of introducing counterfeits and gas stations are popular targets.

Comment: @Mikey It's might worth trying a fuel station, but there is a high chance of refusal as explained by FreeMan. The likelihood of success will probably depend on the location.  In a big city you can probably forget it.  In rural areas, you may be as likely to find a gas station owner who would *give* you a $5 snack (a guaranteed loss of perhaps $3 cost to the owner) rather than break a $100 bill to sell you one (a probable gain of $2 profit but a possible loss of the $3 cost plus $95 cash if the note is counterfeit).

Comment: @FreeMan, splitting hairs at this point, but gas stations don't take bills larger than a $50 or $20 because they have a policy of never keeping that much money in the register.  Counterfeit happens, but robbery is more common and it is common practice for cash to be "stripped" from the register and put into a safe any time there's more than about $100 in it (depending on location, company policies, etc).

Comment: @JPhi1618 Are you sure about that? They'd literally have to empty the register after every 2-4 fuel purchases if they really don't keep more than $100 in the register. I know they try to minimize cash in the register, but $100 seems extremely low, especially at times when gas prices are high (which they're thankfully not right now.) Granted, the vast majority of people probably pay for gas with cards these days, but some do still use cash. I've seen several places that explicitly stated that counterfeiting was the reason they don't accept $100 notes.

Comment: @reirab, yea, it's a combination of how busy the station is and many people just using credit cards.  Also, I'm not talking about some big safe in a back room - it's a secure steel box under the counter that they can quickly and easily dump cash into.  Its something secure enough that a robber can't get into it in a few minutes with some kind of slot to make it easy for a cashier to stick money in.  Time-lock change machines are also used so a cashier can get rolls of ones or coins without a robber being able to access it.  Oh, and counterfeit is certainly a concern too, just not the only one.

Comment: Social science has revealed armed robbers won't risk arrest for less than $200.   7-11’s have a magic safe that accepts and returns money.  It is time constrained so it will only give out $60 or something per 10 minute period or something like that.  I would imagine repeated requests would sound an alarm.

Comment: +1 hotels usually want you to tip their employees, and are usually happy to facilitate that by making change for customers.

Comment: @reirab in addition, ever more often the cash payments go directly into a locked box which contains mechanisms to count out change and return it, linked to the cash register. Not sure if those are programmed to reject large denominations on general principle, but they very well may be.

Comment: You can also try to get change off tipped employees. They often are stuck with bundles of ones and are happy to trade them away for larger denomination bills.

Answer (score 1):

It is common for retailers to provide change (we call this "breaking a bill".) Almost any major chain retailer will break a $100 for a small transaction. You may get attitude though because places like Wal-Mart may have to get extra manager approval to accept the bill or test it using a chemical ink to ensure it is not counterfeit but they will usually do it anyway after hassling you. A smaller business like a gas/petrol station may entirely refuse to accept the bill. Breaking a $100 bill is almost always possible but almost always a hassle.

Since you're asking this, you may also be interested in knowing:

Getting/using coins is not always easy but may be necessary. Many coin operated machines in the US accept quarters only. If you find yourself needing quarters ($0.25) you can usually get them in laundromats from a change machine in exchange for $1 or $5 bills. I run into this all the time when trying to pay for parking. Also, retailers have the right to refuse to accept payment in "burdensome" quantities of small coins. No, you should not pay for a cheeseburger with 600 pennies. In fact, many places will only accept coins if you are paying in exact change. People hate pennies. They are damaging our economy, it costs 2.5 cents to make a 1 cent penny. We only manufacture them still because of Zinc lobbyists and Lincoln fans.

Apple/Google Pay are quickly becoming widely accepted as forms of payment but you should always ask before accepting a service.

In the US, you will often be offered services before you pay. This confuses many tourist who end up getting in trouble once they have consumed a product or service not realizing their method of payment will not be accepted. An example is ordering street food without realizing they are expecting cash only. You probably won't get into any serious trouble but you'll likely get harassed or belittled.

Comment: Tourists are also often surprised when they have the money in hand for the 3.5 USD  cake, to discover that this is actually 3.78 USD because taxes are not included. This always gets me when in the US.